# Returning a dictionary after iteration

Tags: python

I have my dictionary iterating over my integer array the way I want and get my desired result with print but only get the first iteration when I use a `return` statement

```
for i in range(0, N):
    new_dic.update({i:Vk_s[i]})
    print(new_dic)
```

out:

```
{0: 0}
{0: 0, 1: 0}
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 4}
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 4, 4: 5}
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6}
```

vs

```
for i in range(0, N):
     new_dic.update({i:Vk_s[i]})
     return(new_dic)

print(new_dic)
```

out:

```
{0: 0}
```

Comment: Please share full code.

Comment: Your `return` statement is returning on the first iteration of the loop. Outdent it one level.

Comment: ? you are returning after the first iteration of loop, ofc there's only 1 item in the dict

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please carefully note that `print` and `return` have **nothing to do with each other**. The reason the code with `return` only shows one key is that there is only one key in the dict when `return` happens. It is only possible to return once from a given call to the function. Put everything in the dictionary *first*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it appears your indentation is off. You return after a single iteration of the loop:

> ```
> for i in range(0, N):
>    new_dic.update({i:Vk_s[i]})
>    return(new_dic)
> ```

Assuming this is the body of a function, you may want:

```
for i in range(0, n):
    new_dic.update({i: Vk_s[i]})

return new_dic
```

Secondly, are you certain you don't want a dictionary comprehension?

```
{i: Vk_s[i] for i in range(0, N)}
```